# Best practice to implement a user event tracking log aggregation system?

Tags: apache-kafka, real-time, apache-flink

I am struggling in the internship and I was told to implement a system to track the real-time aggregation of the user event.

The input data coming from the Kafka cluster. For simplicity, let us say the schema is

```
{"userId" = "AAA", "region" = "US", {"like" = 1}}
```

And I have to aggregate the result to every 5 minutes, every 1 hour and every day for the machine learning team and operation team and have fault tolerance for network shaking. They want data aggregated like the count of like every 5 minutes but it is not arbitrary it must be like 10:00 - 10:05 10:05 - 10:10. Same for the hour and day.

So I have to compare with the system time to decide with the bucket should the element goes in and calculates the aggregation within that bucket.

Firstly, I am trying to solve the problem by trying to use tools like Flink with window. I find 3 windows with a size of 5 min, 1 hour and 1 day. And use the onElement callback for the edge condition the whole time point. But the memory load is unpredictable some time there are lots of different users stay in the window and cause some node performance problem.

So I have to use some KV storage as the intermediate value for partially calculated data.

And I use Redis cluster to hold the KV storage. But seems the Flink hit the Redis too much, the throughput of Flink is much higher than Redis. The DAU is about 10M globally.

Seems there is only one way that modifies the Rocketdb attached to Flink and implements some cache rather than deletes the window.

I am wondering anyone implements this kind of system before, and give me some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: You could do this with Kafka Streams or KSQL, have you looked at those? Both support stateful aggregation

Comment: Thank for the idea, will take a look at it.

Comment: Did you try to use RocksDB state backend? It is specifically made for use cases when data that you need to hold in state does not fit into memory.